# How can I fix this syntax Error in python

Tags: bash, syntax, jupyter-notebook

```
%%bash
cd models/research/
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
python -m pip install -q .
```

This code gives this error.

```
cd models/research/
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: That is not python code

Comment: Python tags removed as not relevant to the question

Comment: Do you really run this as Python? In this case, none of your statements are valid in Python. However, the error message also does not look like a bash message. I wonder what you are really doing here....